# unwinding segue or forward segue?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have this configuration of viewControllers and segues on a storyboard.

[image]

Application starts at A. A presents two choices to the user: create a new project or load a new project.

**User chooses to create a new project**

The user then goest to B and creates stuff, proceeding to Preview to see it rendered. At Preview the user can save the project and can also go forward to file manager to load another project. If the user chooses to go to the file manager, after loading a project the app unwinds the segue to preview. This is the normal flux (black lines).

**User chooses to load a project**

Another flux is this. The user starts the app at A and chooses to load a project. Then the app goes directly to the file manager where a project can be load. Here is my problem. The app cannot unwind to preview because it jumped from A to file manager, so the app has to go forward to preview. If I do that, the user cannot modify the project, because the part that allows modification is on B (green lines flux). Also, if I go to preview from file manager I will have an inconsistency because at one time the preview's back button will go to B and on another instance to the file manager.

How do I solve that? I cannot go from file manager to B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would amend your flow, so that:

a) The `File Manager` scene seques into `Scene B`.  If you want the user to be taken straight to the `Preview` scene in this case, then just implement an immediate segue into `Preview`.  Then from the `Preview` scene you can unwind to `Scene B` to undertake further edits, etc.

b) When the user saves the project in the `Preview` scene, don't segue forward to `File Manager`.  Unwind all the way back to `Scene A`.  The user will then be presented with the option of creating another new project (segue straight to `Scene B`), or loading an existing one (segue to `File Manager`).

Comment: ok, but here is another problem: if I go from the file manager to B, I can reach the file manager again by going forward and so I can go to B, then to file manager, creating a pile of view controllers to be loaded on memory, if I just go forward...

Comment: I'm suggesting you never go forward from Preview to File Manager - instead you go back all the way to A.

Comment: I suppose that is the best way! THANKS!